# How to show the 40 items of an array with the numbering starting from 1 to 40 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexing

There is an array of 10 students below in the code part.
I wanted to display that as

1. Aaran
2. Aaren
3. Aarez ...up to 10

but I am unable to achieve this using for a loop as the index starts from 0 but if I start it from 1 then it skips the first name.

Here is my code below:

```js
var stu = ["Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Aaryn", "Aayan"]

// 1. counting the students names:
var ln = stu.length;

//2. showing the students names using for loop with numbering:
for (var i = 1; i < ln; i++) {
  document.write(i + " : " + stu[i] + "<br>")
}
```

It gives me numbers like 1, 2, 3 but it skips the first item of the array.
So how can I achieve this without skipping?

Comment: [Why is document.write considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @riyoz, answers go down there.

Comment: I would look at [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). Keep in mind that index is zero-based.

Comment: You have the variable `i` which is starting from 0. So you need to always print `i+1`. If you do not understand any part of this let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Change i=0 and i+1 at write.

```js
    var stu =  ["Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Aaryn", "Aayan"]
    for (var i = 0; i<stu.length; i++){ 
        document.write(  i+1 + " : " + stu[i] + "<br>")
    }
```

Comment: great, it worked perfectly...Thank you so much for this help...God bless

Answer (score 0):

The variable "i" should be 0, the first index in arrays always start with 0, so it should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<ln; i++) {
    document.write(  i + 1 + " : " + stu[i] + "<br>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try iterating array like this:

```
for(let i in stu){
     document.write((i+1) + " : " + stu[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach`, its easier to work with.
[JavaScript Array forEach() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

The `array.forEach` access directly the array elements, so you dont need to use a `for` loop accessing them by their indexes.

Exemple:

```js
var stu = ["Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Aaryn", "Aayan"]

stu.forEach((element, index) => {
  document.write(index + " : " + element + "<br>");
});


document.write('<br>If you want to show it as 1 to 10, them just add 1 to the "index" variable in the "document.write". Be sure to separate it in a new scope to prevent errors. <br><br>');

stu.forEach((element, index) => {
  document.write((index + 1) + " : " + element + "<br>");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
for(let i = 0; i<stu.length; i++){
     document.write((i+1) + " : " + stu[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: oh great, it worked perfectly...Thank you so much for this help...God bless